# Update a table based on match with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an update query where I need to update a column LOB of table SID from two other tables.

Below are the three tables involved:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My requirement is below:

1. Match acc_grid of SID with grid of DMM and update the LOB of SID.
2. For the records where no match found in DMM ( e.g. 100045) , look for this grid in Matrix. Matching condition will be GRID of Matrix and acc_grid of SID.
   Get the DR_GRID of that GRID in Matrix ( which will be same).
3. Find this DR_GRID in DMM and then update the SID.

How can i achieve the same in a single update query (if possible).

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; it uses `merge` with union of two sets: one represents `dmm` table, and another is outer join of `dmm` and `matrix`. It results in all possible combinations of `grid + lob` so all you have to do is to match `sid` to that union set on the `grid` value.

```
SQL> merge into sid s
  2    using (select m.grid, d.lob
  3           from dmm d join matrix m on m.dr_grid = d.grid
  4           union
  5           select d.grid, d.lob
  6           from dmm d
  7          ) x
  8    on (x.grid = s.acc_grid)
  9    when matched then update set
 10      s.lob = x.lob;

3 rows merged.

SQL> select * From sid;

  ACC_GRID LOB
---------- ---
    100015 G
    100045 G
    234546 G

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot ..Wasn't aware that i could do like this.